# Access- Select query or crosstab?

Tags: database, ms-access

New to Access here and I'm having trouble querying a table to give me the desired format.  I have used crosstabs before to get what I want, but in this case its a little different where I'm using dates on both the row and column so its a little difficult to do crosstabs with.

So I have the table on the left, and I want the format on the right.  I want the sum of both method1 and method2 for that particular month for that particular year. Location doesnt really have any bearing in this case. I am more comfortable with design view or wizard, but I'm thinking its probably more flexible to do it in sql view.  Can each column have its own independent query for 2019, 2020?  Or whatever way it can be achieved. (FYI the numbers in this example are fictitious and does not add up btw) Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the two fields in CROSSTAB. Extract date parts to use as row and column headers.

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Method1 + Method2) AS SumMethods
SELECT Month([TransactionDate]) AS Mo, Format([TransactionDate],"mmm") AS Mon
FROM Table
GROUP BY Month([TransactionDate]), Format([TransactionDate],"mmm")
PIVOT Year([TransactionDate]);
```

Comment: Holy Cow that worked!  Thanks, i'll try to understand these some more by looking at reverse understanding it from the design view.  Thanks!

Comment: would you say that its more flexible to build a query from sql view, or both that and design view more the same?

Comment: I use design view to build query, or at least get something started then switch to SQL if I need to. Some queries can only be built in SQL, such as UNION.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I will surely use this knowledge to continue my journey.